# Searching in Different Node in Realtime database

Tags: json, search, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I have a sample Firebase Realtime Database like this:

```
XYZDBName:
{
  users:
  {
      uid1:
      {
         name: "ABC"   
      }       
      uid2:
      {
         name: "XYZ"
      }
  }
  feeds: 
  {
      postid:
      {
          content: "Hello"
          madeby: "ABC"
      }
  }
}
```

Where the node users, keeps a track of signed in users along with their names. If user ABC makes a post, the post is inserted in the feeds node.

Now after posting, I need to know the name using the uid.
I can get the uid by using `getCurrentUser().getUid();`,
but how do I traverse to the users node in order to match it?

Comment: Don't store the users name. Store their uid in the postid node.

Comment: @Jay Alright, but in the output, I would need to display the name of the user who posted it. How to do that?

Comment: Read the node in to get the content and uid. Then with the uid, you can directly look up the user info from the user node via an observeSingleEvent (Swift) or whatever the function is in your platform.